# how to give permission to the user in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have made a simple calculater in that i have 4 button ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV  & I have two user
i want to give the permission to the user in such a way that user 1 is able to see only ADD & SUB & user 2 is able to see only MUL & DIV

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CustomPermission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_custompermission.htm) for this. Create various new Custom Permissions to describe the user's permissions, then you can assign that value through a Permission Set for each user. From there, you can then [check the user's Custom Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_get_permissions).

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import hasAddSubPermission from '@salesforce/customPermission/AddSub';
import hasMultDivPermission from '@salesforce/customPermission/MultDiv';

export default class Calculator extends LightningElement {
  canAddSub = hasAddSubPermission;
  canMultDiv = hasMultDivPermission;
  // ...
}
```

---

```
<lightning-button if:true={canAddSub} label="Add"></lightning-button>
<lightning-button if:true={canAddSub} label="Subtract"></lightning-button>
<lightning-button if:true={canMultDiv} label="Multiply"></lightning-button>
<lightning-button if:true={canMultDiv} label="Divide"></lightning-button>
```

This is just an example, you can make it however you'd like. We're just demonstrating custom permissions here.